# Get plain javascript object (or JSON-ready object) from mongoose document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given the created document from the `.save` method, or any other method that returns a document, how would I convert that document to a plain javascript object with primitive JSON types? I've tried `.toJSON` and `.toObject` but they both still maintain mongoose's ObjectId data type, when I want a string instead:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });
const kitty = new Cat({ name: 'aed' });

kitty.save()
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.toObject()._id instanceof mongoose.Types.ObjectId)
    console.log(data.toJSON()._id instanceof mongoose.Types.ObjectId)
    console.log(data.toObject({ virtuals: true, getters: true })._id instanceof mongoose.Type.ObjectId)
    console.log(data.toJSON({ virtuals: true, getters: true })._id instanceof mongoose.Types.ObjectId)
    return data
})
.then(data => data.remove())
.catch(console.error);
```

```
true
true
true
true
```

I know I can use `.lean()`, but I specifically need to the document as well as its plain object version

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use `toObject`, then `JSON.stringify`, and then `JSON.parse`.

```js
router.post("/cat", (req, res) => {
  const kitty = new Cat({ name: "Masha" });

  kitty.save().then(data => {
    const obj = data.toObject();
    const str = JSON.stringify(obj);
    const json = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(typeof json._id);
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

The result of `console.log(typeof json._id)` will be `string`.

Also to remove version key, we can apply `versionKey` false option in the schema definition.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }, { versionKey: false });

const Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);

module.exports = Cat;
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't help with subdocuments that still have mongoose types, such as arrays of ObjectIds (i want to keep the _id by the way, it's just that I want everything converted to native JS types). I keep looking everywhere and it looks like there's no actual method to purge all of mongoose Types to just give a simple object...

Comment: @platizin I updated the answer, the returned document's type is already object. Maybe I didn't fully understand your question.

Comment: I'd like to convert the document into a *plain* object of the document with no mongoose types, and only primitive JSON types. For example, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(document))`, completely removing all mongoose types from the data, but a way to force a document to become that without using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @platizin ok but I showed that it is already a plain javascript object. We can exclude the __v field

Comment: That's using express and using the `.send` which serializes it with its own methods (probably JSON.parse/stringify?) - I'd like to do somehow do that with mongoose methods, and use it in my own application (since I'm not trying to send it back to a client with a web server)

Comment: @platizin typeof data is object, what is the problem? You can use the data as plain object

Comment: The problem is it's not a plain object with primitive JSON types - I updated my question to reflect that. The `_id`s are not converted to string, and still maintain their `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` types, which also means any subdocuments will also maintain mongoose types

Comment: @platizin I understood. Can you please check the updated answer?

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to avoid as I mentioned in my comments, but I guess there's no other way. Thanks.

Comment: @platizin you are welcome,  I appreciate if you can also upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can spread that document (see example below). But in that case you will lose properties that is extended from parent prototype.

console.log({...data});

Comment: I'm trying to get a plain javascript object with no mongoose types - the console log was just a means to explain the two methods were not working as I wanted them to. I updated my answer to make that clearer